# How to select data from one table and select count to another table and combine it in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In one fruit there can be multiple tickets that can be raised. I need to display the number of tickets raised per fruit. Their key field is the **fruit_id**.

[image: sample output picture]

Comment: Is your output correct? The second row has `apple222`, shouldn't it be `orangee222`?

Comment: ohh that is orange222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have the following tables:

#### fruit

```
id    name
 1    apple
 2    orange
```

#### tickets

```
id  fruit_id
 1         1
 2         1
 3         2
 4         2
 5         2
```

Then I would use the following SQL syntax to output a table like the one you need:

```
SELECT fruit.id, fruit.name, COUNT(tickets.id)
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN fruit ON fruit.id = tickets.fruit_id
GROUP BY fruit.id;
```

Output:

```
id     name   COUNT(tickets.id)
 1    apple                  2
 2   orange                  3
```

Comment: ill thumbs up this once i earn my reputation

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Fruit.Fruit ID,Fruit.Fruit Name, count(Ticket.Ticket Id) as match_rows FROM Fruit LEFT Join Ticket on (Fruit.Fruit ID = Ticket.Fruit ID) group by Fruit.Fruit Id ORDER BY Fruit.Fruit ID DESC

Comment: It's better you put the reason why you give the op this query and how the query work.. Rather than just put up your messy query..

Comment: ill thumbs up this once i earn my reputation